# Realoding an scene doesn't load the content of a variable from another script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need help solving a problem I just find while scripting for Unity3D.

This is my case:

I have 5 cards on a table. One card will add a point to the score while the other 4 will take a life away. The right card is ramdomly choose on a script attached to a different object present on the scene.

In my first card I have this script attached

```
public void SelectCard()
{
    switch (externalVariable)
    {
        case 1:
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("You win a point!");
            Application.LoadLevel("Mini Game 1");
            break;

        case 2:
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("You lose a life!!!");
            Application.LoadLevel("Mini Game 1");
            break;

        case 3:
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("You lose a life!!!");
            Application.LoadLevel("Mini Game 1");
            break;

        case 4:
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("You lose a life!!!");
            Application.LoadLevel("Mini Game 1");
            break;

        case 5:
            UnityEngine.Debug.Log("You lose a life!!!");
            Application.LoadLevel("Mini Game 1");
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, if the random number is one the player will score one point if he choose the first card, but if the random number is different and the player choose the first card, he will lose a life.

The random number is stored on a int variable. To acces it, I add this to the start() section of the script attached on the first card

```
externalVariable= externalObject.GetComponent<MiniGame1RightCard>().rightCard;
UnityEngine.Debug.Log("The right card is card number: " + externalVariable);
```

So, the first card will access the random number generated by the external script attached to a different object present on the same scene, store it, and then tell me by console output which one is the right card. Then, when the player clic the first card, the script will compare the random number stored on externalVariable to check if the first card is actually the right card or not. Either way, the last step is reload the same scene to start all over again.

The very fist time the scene is loaded everything runs perfect. My problem start with the second time the scene is loaded: externalVariable is always zero. Now for the tricky part, if I put the very same code on the Update() section instead of the Start() section, for one or two seconds the externalVariable stays at zero and then change for the random number generated.

My guess is, I'm doing something wrong when I reload the scene to start again, but I don't know what.

Any ideas about why the code works fine the very first time on the Start() section and every single time on the Update() section???

UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE.

The whole code attached to card1

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Threading;

public class Card1: MonoBehaviour
{
   private string querySeleccionar = "SELECT Nivel FROM LevelAndDifficultyWHERE id=1;";
   Text textoSilaba1;
 public GameObject cardImage1;
 public int level;
 public int externalVariable;
 public GameObject objetoExterno;

 public void SeleccionarSilaba()
 {
     switch (externalVariable)
     {
         case 1:
             UnityEngine.Debug.Log("You win a point!");
             Application.LoadLevel("Mini Juego 1");
             break;

         case 2:
             UnityEngine.Debug.Log("You lose a life!!!");
             Application.LoadLevel("Mini Juego 1");
             break;

         case 3:
             UnityEngine.Debug.Log("You lose a life!!!");
             Application.LoadLevel("Mini Juego 1");
             break;

         case 4:
             UnityEngine.Debug.Log("You lose a life!!!");
             Application.LoadLevel("Mini Juego 1");
             break;

         case 5:
             UnityEngine.Debug.Log("You lose a life!!!");
             Application.LoadLevel("Mini Juego 1");
             break;
     }
 }

 public void OnMouseDown()
 {

 }

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start ()
 {
     //lot of database stuff

     switch (level)
     {
         case 1:

         //lots of cases
     }
     externalVariable= externalObject.GetComponent<MiniGame1RightCard>().rightCard;
     UnityEngine.Debug.Log("The right card is card number: " + externalVariable);
     }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
 {

 }
}
```

The script that generate the random number

```
     using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class MiniGame1RightCard: MonoBehaviour
 {
     public int rightCard;

     // Use this for initialization
     void Start ()
     {
         silabaCorrecta = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1, 5);
         UnityEngine.Debug.Log("The right card is card number " + rightCard);
     }

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update ()
     {

     }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

As Neeraj already mentioned you are generating your randoms and trying to get it's values on the same game cycle (that runs just once per object creation) and Unity can execute them in any order (between both of them any can run first so if Unity runs your card script before your random generator it will not work cause you didn't created your random values yet).

The easily solution is to run your random generator logic at Awake() method instead of Start().

Also, you can take a look in some good programming practices, as I see you comment that there is a lot of cases in your conditional switches maybe you can apply a better modeling using polymorphism properly. (just google something like "changing switches for polymorphism" or somethink like this and research a little)

Comment: Thank you, using an Awake() method for the random number generator worked so fine. About your suggestion, I'm using switches because is a reading game for down sindrome kids and I'm following the syllabic method for teaching them how to read. Based on that I need to split words into syllables. In level one the syllables follow the rule of vocal-consonant or consonant-vocal because the syllable is made with just two letters, but in level two they follow the rule of vocal-consonant-vocal, or vocal-vocal-consonant, or consonant-vocal-consonant, or consonant-consonant-vocal,

Comment: or consonant-vocal-vocal, or vocal-consonant-consonant, because the syllables are made with three letters. My problem is, in spanish there are sometimes where a syllable doesn't have words, like "ox", there are no words that begins with syllable ox in spanish. So, using an automatic rule for generating the syllables doesn't seens fit to me. Same principle for polymorphism. But hey, what the hell do I know?, maybe is possible. So far I have 400 cases and I just started letter P, I'm guessing that the remaining eleven letters will take it up to... IDK, 700 cases?

Answer (score 0):

This is a expected behavior in unity, because whenever scene loads then previous gameobjects and scripts always gets destroyed and recreated again. If you want to preserve the script file or gameobject which is generating random number, you have to make that class a persistent class, so it doesn't get destroyed on scene load.

here is example of generic persistent class
using UnityEngine;

```
//This is the parent class of all the singlton classes
public class Persistent<T> : MonoBehaviour
    where T : Component
{
    private static T instance;
    public static T Instance {
        get {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = FindObjectOfType<T> ();
                if (instance == null) {
                    GameObject obj = new GameObject ();
                    //obj.hideFlags = HideFlags.HideAndDontSave;
                    instance = obj.AddComponent<T> ();
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

    public virtual void Awake ()
    {
        //DontDestroyOnLoad (this.gameObject);
        if (instance == null) {
            instance = this as T;
        } else {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        }
    }
}
```

now if you inherit any class from this class will not destroy on scene load. And this how you can inherit from this class.

```
public class MiniGame1RightCard : Persistent<MiniGame1RightCard>
```

Comment: Ok, I did understand the fact that when an scene is loaded all objects and scripts are destroyed. When my scene reloads the script generating the random number is started and it actually generate the random number without problems. My problem begins when from another scritp I try to access the variable that contains the random number. By what you just told me, when an scene is reloaded everything is recreated again, so, if the script I use to access that variable is recreated, when the script is reloaded it should access the variable. So far it seems like it does, but somehow

Comment: it takes a value of zero. On runtime I watch the variable and is not a zero, but a random number. The variable Y on script B that is going to contain the random number generated on script A stored on variable X, always is filled with a zero value, even if the value of X is a number, any number. If the problem is caused by the reload of the scene and the destruction of all objects and scripts, then why it works fine inside an Update() section?. Yes, for what I need to do I could just use an Update() call,but then the script is going to fill X with Y's content 3600 times per minute

Comment: are you generating your random number in start or awake function? seems like you are having execution order problem then. You need to post your script to find the possible issues.

Comment: I think some part of code is missing in you MiniGame1RightCard class, I can see you are storing random number in "silabaCorrecta", not in rightCard. Any ways if you are assigning random number to rightCard in Start function, then that is the problem.